# User with blank detail in output

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, blank

As per the attached screenshot, I need a formula to derive user with a blank cell to be shown as pending. (Pending has been manually entered.)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What formula have you tried?

Comment: just filter the data, or use `filter()`

Comment: Data from Column F to N is in different excel sheet.